# Solspace Calendar -> Playa -> Tagger

Tags: solspace, calendar

My question is.. 
I have a calendar:event channel with a custom Playa field 
In the related playa field i have Tagger.. How can i filter the event i show using the tags!?

I already have this -->
{exp:calendar:cal calendar_id="9" date_range_start="today @ now" date_range_end="tomorrow @ 2359" dynamic="off" pad_short_weeks="n"}

{event_start_date format="%d-%Hh%i"}{calendar_serie var_prefix="serieX"}{serieX:title}{/calendar_serie}

{/exp:calendar:cal}

Then i was able to filter the "serie" using this 
 {exp:tagger:entries tag="horaire_accueil" limit="4"}

{tagger:entry_title}

{/exp:tagger:entries}

How can i "merge' these 2!?

Regards
Ben